# Kafkastream - spring cloud stream - custom tolopogy without bindings in configuration file

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

This projects don't describe classic bindings in application config file, we override the StreamsBuilderFactoryBean definition like this to be able to generate the topology manually.

```
@Bean
public StreamsBuilderFactoryBean createSBFB(){

   StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilderFactoryBean = new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(streamConfiguration);

        streamsBuilderFactoryBean.setInfrastructureCustomizer(
                new KafkaStreamsInfrastructureCustomizer() {
                    @Override
                    public void configureBuilder(StreamsBuilder builder) {
                          builder.stream(...) // here we append our topology
                    }
               }
}
```

This is perfectly working but we are loosing healthcheck mecanism, and kafkastream actuator metrics.

Is there a way to work around ?
the main goal is to retrieve the topology from a rest service. Can we use spring cloud stream in this context ?

Comment: Is the main goal here is to get access to the topology as a bean? Also, what do you mean by "don't describe classic bindings in application config file"? Thanks.

Comment: Hello Soby, Topology is retrieved from a rest service,  so input topics and output topics are defined outside my container. The goal is to build dynamically our topology. May be a non sense to use spring cloud stream in this context.